# How to use MySql select with c#

Tags: c#, mysql, select

Can anyone tell whats wrong with my code? I have tried a million different things and I cant seem to make it work. I need to make a select in my mysql database and use the id from the table with the specified name I take from a combobox.

I took that name from the combobox and put it into a variable named "nomeres", now I need to do a select with it and take the id from that name from the database. Everything I try to do results in a mysql syntax error in line 1, but I've tried alot of things and its always the same. The database is fine, I tried the select directly from it myself, no tables or columns names are incorrect. This is the code im using:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection dbConn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection("Persist Security Info=False;server=localhost;database=notas;uid=root;password=" + dbpwd);

MySqlCommand cmd = dbConn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id from residentes WHERE nome ='" + nomeres;

try
{
    dbConn.Open();                
} catch (Exception erro) {
    MessageBox.Show("Erro" + erro);
    this.Close();
}

MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    idnumber = reader.ToString();
}
```

Comment: next time you attempt the command, I highly recommend trying the sql command on a test table or, on the real table. Possibly doing this with PHPMyAdmin or something along those lines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to terminate the string in the query:

```
"SELECT id from residentes WHERE nome ='" + nomeres + "'"
```

In general, when trying to debug this type of code, it helps to print out the query string after all substitutions have been made.

Comment: Same error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' SELECT id from residentes WHERE nome ='afslavas'' at line 1

Comment: Btw, it highlights the "MySqlDataReader" line when shows this error. Dont know if that is relevant.

Comment: **Do not do this.** This introduces a SQL injection vulnerability, and there's no excuse for not using parameterized queries these days (especially with a library like Dapper). It also will break if you have a literal single quote in your variable.

Comment: @gregmac . . . BTW, I agree.  You should really be using parameters for the query.

Answer (score 17):

as others have already pointed you towards right direction,
 i would like to suggest you to use `parameterised queries` to avoid `SQL injection attacks`.

Your query is open to `SQL injection attacks` so please read [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)

Try This: using `parameterised SQL queries`

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id from residentes WHERE nome = @nome";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome",nomeres);
```

Comment: Thx for the tip, but it will be a local application.

Comment: @user3126468: though it is a local application you could use `parameterised queries` as they also take care of `DatTypes` to be passed properly.

Comment: @martin.koch You can still be attacked from someone/something locally. Your code may 'grow up' and end up being used for something bigger and internet-facing. This is how a lot of bad/insecure code gets into production, frankly. Parameters are not difficult to use, and I'd argue they are actually easier as they avoid all the nonsense of escaping values, type conversion, plus your SQL is far more readable.

Answer (score 3):

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id from residentes WHERE nome ='" + nomeres + "';";

Actually you miss the semicolon of the query that have to enter within the quotes. The second semicolon is for the end of statement.
But I prefer to write commands like:

```
 cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id from residentes WHERE nome = @nome";
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", variableName);
```

Then execute the query and retrieve your results.

Answer (score 1):

Missing single quote:

```
"SELECT id from residentes WHERE nome ='" + nomeres + "'";
                                                       ^
```